# How to get only the updated child data from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, key-value, firebase-storage

I am able to fetch the all the child node from the firebase database.

```
 Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://myfiebase-url.firebaseio.com/");
    firebase.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            Log.e("testing message", dataSnapshot.getValue() + "--->")
            }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
```

[image]

But my problem is that when any new data add inside node for example if one more data is added inside node 2. 
At that time `onDataChange()` return the complete data. I want to retrieve only the updated data.

Now I am getting this response:

```
E/testing message: [null, {-KrBu6CM_IP7xwQHcYOT={date=10-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Thu Aug 10 21:39:32 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Gagsgs, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXiYBOUqeZ7BtzF9jw={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 03:20:38 IST 2017, message=Fggffg, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KquvlHuja1PZ-hoW-Xf={date=07-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Mon Aug 07 09:53:35 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Xvxcggg, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXb8scQ3blRzt3HzUX={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:48:20 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Tggggg, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXatbjGvt8HlZetAHN={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:47:13 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Gggfy, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXaZINL9_ZEAMbVE_1={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:45:46 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Shubhank, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXbBgEhJA3CMlHlTtX={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:48:31 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Tyyggg, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXfVrqlVw8OXPOzjlw={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 03:07:22 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Fggh, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXaV5zkbz369g4n2_N={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:45:28 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Gghhu, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXb2rZgm98Jiu8dZ7I={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:47:55 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Ytttt, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXb1Mkp1pir5PekCGp={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:47:49 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Ttttt, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXacX7z-InOYNLa6zB={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:46:03 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Eeqdss, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXagbxXVN5dx1YkPBD={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:46:20 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Mn mm, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXcbNyUQo8ia7WRoO1={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:54:43 IST 2017, message=Bdhdhdd, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXcZLhA5RVJceDPai6={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:54:30 IST 2017, message=Xdff, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXagsuQ2iLmJVhbnoi={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:46:21 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Lp, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXhz1XeWxYguDNt8Yv={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 03:18:10 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Fhfdt, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXanJdSh9iPqCJCUT0={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:46:47 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Ghjhh, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXb-jZqlwOEbUswppw={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:47:42 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Dfgffg, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXeHxow-Jb5n0LuW5s={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 03:02:03 IST 2017, message=Ftffft, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXcV2Og5InEEtDacMj={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:54:13 IST 2017, message=Gfggg, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXb6zFyP5DnaexkMmU={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:48:12 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Tttt, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXc4bhHWZsQfbVj8HU={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:52:25 IST 2017, message=Vhhhh, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KquvqzMKh3eNEnIzhhr={date=07-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Mon Aug 07 09:53:59 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Gdgsggdd, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXayJVxlC3hXqSiVnF={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:47:32 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Frsddr, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KqqdBq5Ui8Ij-jg5kN2={date=06-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Sun Aug 06 13:53:59 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Gfggg, userId=0, timeStamp=}}, {-KrXSl1kSbbQF38mHXtb={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:07:18 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Gggg, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrX6yitdWGiBF4SR2MJ={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 00:32:08 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Gggg, userId=0, timeStamp=}, -KrXTEKQpj1Sz7qUkgRp={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 02:09:23 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Cffg, userId=0, timeStamp=}}, {-KrXLO1INF4-0HewRVD7={date=15-08-2017, stared=, chatId=, time=Tue Aug 15 01:35:05 GMT+05:30 2017, message=Aastha, userId=0, timeS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get told what specific child node has been modified, you should use Firebase's `ChildEventListener`:

```
firebase.addChildEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) {
        Log.i("onChildAdded", "Child "+dataSnapshot.getKey()+" was added after "+previousChildKey)
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i("onChildRemoved", "Child "+dataSnapshot.getKey()+" was removed")
    }
    ...
```

The [`onChild*` methods](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-types) tell you exactly what happened: `onChildAdded`, `onChildRemoved`, `onChildChanged` and `onChildMoved`.

Btw: you're using a Firebase SDK that is at least a year and a half old and hasn't been updated since. I **highly*** recommend that you switch over to a new version of the [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). If you're looking to convert existing code, look at the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).

Comment: but actually I want to detect if the new node is added under sub-child. suppose if node added inside 4 or 3.

Comment: There is no way to listen for `onGrandchild*` events in the Firebase Database SDK. You'll have to change your data model to accommodate your use-case.

Comment: Thanks, Frank...there is any way to fetch data of multiple nodes using 'addListenerForSingleValueEvent'